# link to archive.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have the following code in my single.php which outputs the following links

[image]

```
<div class="dt"><?php echo get_the_date();?></div>

<div class="cat">
<?php the_category(', ');?>
</div>

<div class="tag">
  <?php the_tags();?>

</div>

<div class="arc">
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ); ?>">Archives</a>
</div>
```

both links to category and tag are working producing output via category.php and tag.php, however, I can't figure it out how to link to archive.php where I plan to show post archive

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know there is no full archive page like you describe created by default.

Refer to this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
        </ul>

        <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
        <ul>
             <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Access the archives like this:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>
```

Comment: I know about the solution you are suggesting. This is not what I am looking for. Please review my screenshot above (see 'Archives' link next to 'Flexbox' and 'Grid' tags)